# OWASP Juice Shop user generation on docker startup

Tags: docker, docker-compose, owasp

I'm trying to have the Juice Shop running on my machine without loosing created users.
Currently I'm using a docker-compose setup which makes it very easy to start and use it locally. 
But what always annoys me is that on restating docker-compose / docker / or my OS entirely all recently created users are gone and I've to create them again :(
What am I missing here?
As far as I found out, there must be a routine creating all users again and puting those into the users table (with always removing my 31st+ user (first 30 are random and some pre-defined as I found out)).

**My Idea:** 
Having the juiceshop.sqlite database being synced outside of the container's volume to not loose it .... but it's getting overridden every time docker is restarting the shop.

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
  juiceShop:
    image: bkimminich/juice-shop
    ports:
      - 80:3000
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=myConfig
    volumes:
      - ./config.yml:/juice-shop/config/myConfig.yml:ro
      - juiceShop:/juice-shop:cached
      - ./juiceShop.sqlite:/juice-shop/data/juiceshop.sqlite:cached

volumes:
  juiceShop:
```

**Further thoughts**

- Is there a config to stop spawning these users?

  - in regular customization description I did not find any mention of the idea (https://pwning.owasp-juice.shop/part1/customization.html)
- Can I (besides a custom script inserting old users) somehow make sure old users will be available on next re-spawning of the juice shop?
- Where is the logic hidden to create those users -> maybe a slight override can stop it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I cannot recommend saving and restoring the SQLite database in any way**, because you might end up with a state where the application can no longer start or will no longer allow you to solve certain challenges. It is pretty common that DB records (especially users and products) are messed up while trying to solve certain challenges. The Juice Shop prevents any issues from persisting by wiping the DB completely:

> *Self-healing-feature*
>
> OWASP Juice Shop was not exactly designed and built with a high availability and reactive enterprise-scale architecture in mind. It runs perfectly fine and fast when it is attacked via a browser by a human. When under attack by an automated tool - especially aggressive brute force scripts - the server might crash under the load. This could - in theory - leave the database and file system in an unpredictable state that prevents a restart of the application.
>
> That is why - in practice - Juice Shop wipes the entire database and the folder users might have modified during hacking. After performing this self-healing the application is supposed to be restartable, no matter what kind of problem originally caused it to crash. For convenience the self-healing happens during the start-up (i.e. npm start) of the server, so no extra command needs to be issued to trigger it.

(Source https://pwning.owasp-juice.shop/part1/running.html)

**There is also intentionally no configuration option for users** except for their email domain and the number of randomly added users on top of the default ones. Changing the users will most likely break a dozen or more challenges.